# creating and using DLLs in visual studio c#

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I have created my first dll using c# and visual studio 2010.  I am trying to use it in a program.  The dll is in the program directory but visual studio will not allow `using myDLL` stating that it could not be found.  I have also tried adding it as a reference in the solution explorer.  What more do I need to do?

Here is one of the files from my class.

```
namespace nbt
{
    class TAG_Long
    {
        private string name;
        private long payload;
        public TAG_Long(FileStream f)
        {
            name = NameTag.SetTagName(f);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)dataBytes.TYPE_LONG];
            f.Read(buffer, 0, (int)dataBytes.TYPE_LONG);
            Array.Reverse(buffer);
            payload = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of DLL is it? is it a managed DLL that was created with C# or is it a "real"/native DLL, like user32.dll, that you created with C++, etc.?

Comment: Please enclose code on what you did so far, we're shooting in the dark like blind people....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your class in a namespace